# WiFi adapter over serial port?

Tags: wireless-networking, serial-port, serial

I just recently came into possession of a old AST Premium Exec notebook computer. The only ports it has are a serial port and a parallel port and it runs DOS. I thought that with the serial port I could get WiFi working with a Serial-to-USB adapter or something and write some software on the DOS end to communicate with the adapter. Anybody know of any WiFi adapters that go over a serial port / work over a serial port?
Note: I have a USB WiFi adapter anyway so if that could work that would be good.
Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember the first time I woke up from a 20 year sleep. :)  Anyway, there are several [RS232 to Wifi adapters](http://www.gridconnect.com/wi232.html) out there ([another](http://www.zcomax.co.uk/web/component/page,shop.product_details/flypage,shop.flypage_zcomax/product_id,242/category_id,109/manufacturer_id,0/option,com_virtuemart/Itemid,26/)).  I've never tied one tho!

Comment: Cool... I'll check it out.